# Submitting a form and run a function at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, forms, function

When I press the Submit button of a form it runs a php file which stores the answer to a db.

Is it possible to use the Submit button of a form to submit the user's choice and immediately after that run a function without further actions from the user?

For example, in the following simple form and php, how can I run a function when the user presses Submit?

```
<form action="db.php" method="post">
  A:<input type="radio" name="answer" value="A">
  B:<input type="radio" name="answer" value="B">
  <input type="submit" name="submit value="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','my user id','my password');
    if(!con) {
        echo 'not connected to server';
    } else {
        echo 'something else is wrong';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'my user id') {
        echo 'Database error selection';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $answer=$_POST['answer'];
        $sql = INSERT INTO test1 (columnName) VALUES ('$answer');
        mysqli_query($con,$sql); // Execute query
    }
?>
```

As an example let's take the following function which is a part of a larger file.

```
function next() {
  var qElems = document.querySelectorAll('#questions>div');
  for (var i = 0; i < qElems.length; i++) {
    if (qElems[i].style.display != 'none') {
      qElems[i].style.display = 'none';
      if (i == qElems.length - 1) {
        qElems[0].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        qElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
      }
      break;
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: Do you want the JS function to run on the same page as the form? You could change the post to be handled by JS and use a promise/ajax call to do the transaction and run the function on completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onsubmit event handler to the form

```
<form action="db.php" method="post" onsubmit="functionToCall()">
```

which will call the given function when the form is submitted. If you want to stop the form from being submitted, return false from the function. As @JokerDan said, you can also use AJAX within your function and omit the form action altogether.

```
function functionToCall() {
  // Do something before you submit your form (save data locally or whatever)

  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //Do something after submitting the form (if you want to change the page or redirect)
    }
  };
  http.open('POST', 'db.php');
  http.send(/*send post data here*/);
}
```

If you want to send data with the AJAX request, you will have to pull it from the form and put it in the http.send() line in the same format you pass data in the URL (data=answer&submit=true)

Comment: I am not very proficient in html/php and I am using a code I found online after I modified it slightly to fit my needs. It's a series of quiz questions and I only need a way to submit the choice and then make the next question appear. Thank you for you suggestions. I will look into them, but I think I will prefer the first one which I understand better.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this, is to first select your form using something like `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementById` (only possible if the form element has an id).

```
var form = document.querySelector('[action="db.php"]');
```

After you selected your form, use the `addEventListener` of your form to add an evenListener.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', myListener, false);
```

Now you'll just need to create a function that looks like this :

```
function myListener(event) {
  // DO STUFF
}
```

Here, `event` is an `object` of type `Event` that provides more information about the form you submitted. This function will be called every time you try to submit your form!